# spring security - logout when session expires and also allowing anonymous user to access the functionality

Tags: spring-security

I have a requirement to redirect to login page when session expires for a logged in user.
However the functionality is accessible as anonymous user (i.e the user not logged in) as well.

A feature "Search Address" is accessible by everyone, meaning logged in users and anonymous users (user not logged in)....

So the requirement is such, that when the user logs in and performs search, it should redirect if session has already expired, however just making it clear the same search should work if we don't login in (i.e anonymous).

An anonymous user is technically logged in, therefore they have a session created as well, however they wouldn't manually type user name/password in to login as opposed to the logged in user

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http security="none" 
        pattern="^/(login\.jsp|customSkin|openlayers|images|js)[/\?].*$"
        request-matcher="regex"/>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">

        <security:anonymous enabled="true" granted-authority="ROLE_GENERIC" />  

        <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="formLoginFilter"/>
        <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="PreAuthenticationFilter"/>

        <!-- <security:logout logout-success-url="/loginUI.jsp" /> -->
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="LogoutSuccessHandler" />
        <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"/>

        <!-- SMES Interceptors -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/Mark**" access="ROLE_ABC_OSGV" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/abc/admin/**" access="ROLE_ABC_OSGV" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/abc/edit/**" access="ROLE_ABC_OSGV,ROLE_ABC_REGISTERED_USER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/abclookup/**" access="ROLE_ABC_OSGV,ROLE_ABC_REGISTERED_USER,ROLE_GENERIC,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_EDIT,ROLE_ABC_ADMIN,ROLE_ABC_HCA" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/general/**" access=
                    "ROLE_ABC,
                    ROLE_GENERIC,
                    ROLE_ADMIN,
                    ROLE_ABC_EXPORT,
                    ROLE_EDIT,
                    ROLE_ABC,
                    ROLE_ABC_TPC,
                    ROLE_ABC_VMT,
                    ROLE_ABC_S,
                    ROLE_ABC_DATA_GENERIC,
                    ROLE_ABC_DATA_ADMIN,
                    ROLE_ABC_OSGV,
                    ROLE_ABC_REGISTERED_USER,
                    ROLE_ABC_ADMIN,
                    ROLE_ABC_HCA,
                    ROLE_ABC_NAMES" />

        <!-- SMES Interceptors -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/vicnames/edit/**" access="ROLE_ABC_ADMIN,ROLE_ABC_HCA" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/vicnames/admin/**" access="ROLE_ABC_ADMIN" />

        <!-- LASSI Interceptors -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/edit/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_EDIT" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/broadcast/save**" access="ROLE_EDIT" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/edmbooking/admin/**" access="ROLE_ABC_BOOKING_ADMIN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/adminUdateLogicaLabels**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_EDIT" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access=
                    "ROLE_DQA,
                    ROLE_GENERIC,
                    ROLE_ADMIN,
                    ROLE_DQA_EXPORT,
                    ROLE_EDIT,
                    ROLE_APS,
                    ROLE_ABC_TPC,
                    ROLE_ABC_VMT,
                    ROLE_ABC_TEST,
                    ROLE_ABC_DATA_GENERIC,
                    ROLE_ABC_DATA_ADMIN,
                    ROLE_ABC_OSGV,
                    ROLE_ABC_REGISTERED_USER,
                    ROLE_ABC_ADMIN,
                    ROLE_ABC_HCA,
                    ROLE_ABC_NAMES" />
        <security:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>

    </security:http>

    <bean id="LogoutSuccessHandler"
        class="LogoutHandlerImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"
        class="CustomHttp403ForbiddenEntryPoint">       
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticationProvider" />
        <security:authentication-provider ref="myProfileAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="preAuthenticationFilter" class="PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter"> 
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="formLoginFilter" class="UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref = "authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref = "authenticationFailureHandler" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        class="AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl">
         <!--<property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/login.jsp"/>-->
         <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationFailureHandler"
        class="AuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <!-- <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/sessionTimeout.jsp?login_error=true"/> -->
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp?login_error=true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="preAuthenticationProvider"
        class="PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="lpreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="lpreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" class="somepreauthenticateduserdetailsservice"/>

    <bean id="myProfileAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.test.AuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="serviceInvoker" ref="authenticationServiceInvoker" />
        <property name="roleMapping">
            <map>
                <entry key="ABC_DQA" value="ROLE_DQA" />
                <entry key="ABC_APS" value="ROLE_APS" />
                <entry key="ABC_EDIT" value="ROLE_EDIT" />
                <entry key="ABC_ADMINISTRATOR" value="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <entry key="ABC_GENERIC" value="ROLE_GENERIC" />
                <entry key="ABC_DQA_EXPORT" value="ROLE_DQA_EXPORT" />
                <entry key="ABC_FOH" value="ROLE_ABC_FOH" />
                <entry key="ABC_TPC" value="ROLE_ABC_TPC" />
                <entry key="ABC_VMT" value="ROLE_ABC_VMT" />
                <entry key="ABC_SPEAR" value="ROLE_ABC_TEST" />
                <entry key="ABC_LANDATA_GENERIC" value="ROLE_ABC_DATA_GENERIC" />
                <entry key="ABC_LANDATA_ADMIN" value="ROLE_ABC_DATA_ADMIN" />
                <entry key="ABC_OSGV"           value="ROLE_ABC_OSGV" />
                <entry key="ABC_Registered_Users" value="ROLE_ABC_REGISTERED_USER" />
                <entry key="ABC_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE" value="ROLE_ABC_ADMIN" />
                <entry key="ABC_HISTORIAN_ROLE" value="ROLE_ABC_HCA" />
                <entry key="ABC_PUBLIC_ROLE" value="ROLE_ABC_NAMES" />
                <entry key="ABC_BOOKING_ADMIN" value="ROLE_EDM_BOOKING_ADMIN" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

     <bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
          class="someaccessdeniedhandler">
        <property name="errorPage" value="/login.jsp?access_denied=true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationServiceInvoker"
        class="com.test.AuthenticationServiceInvoker" />

    <bean id="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
        <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"/>
        <property name="maximumSessions" value="1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>

</beans>




public class CustomHttp403ForbiddenEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint.class);

    /**
     * Always returns a 403 error code to the client.
     */
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException arg2) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access");
        }
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if (request.getUserPrincipal() == null && request.getContentType() != null && request.getContentType().toLowerCase().indexOf("multipart/form-data") > -1 ) {
            returnJSSCript(request, response, "{\"sessionTimeout\":\"true\"}");
        }
        else {
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Access Denied");
        }
    }

    private void returnJSSCript(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response, String msg){
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        try {
            String eventName = "sessionTimeout";
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
            out.println("parent.fireEvent('" + eventName + "','" + msg + "');");
            out.println("</script>");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Could you please let me know how we can redirect to a login page when the user's session has been expired without breaking the search functionality of allowing the anonymous user to still perform the search in Spring Security.

Cheers,
Tech XX

Comment: We have spring backend with request mapping "/general/search.json". This is called from the front end on button click.

Comment: Spring security config has a interceptor pattern "/**", which will take care of users with all roles including role generic.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the search url anon, and take it out to another `http` `configuration`, So it will not be filtered in your `/**` chain(`<security:http entry-point-ref="http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">`).

```
<security:http pattern="/general/search.json" security="none"/>
```

Comment: OK. But how do we allow the logged in user to redirect when the user performs search after session times out. The way it's been done is  spring throws HTTP 403 when the session expires during the time when it's accessing the spring back-end, and based on that we redirect to the login page. However in search functionality where the anonymous user can still perform the search...

Comment: So if we say <security:http pattern="/general/search.json" security="none"/>, it will allow all users to access this pattern, so how do we stop the logged in user to access this service after the session expires and also not breaking the existing search functionality used by anonymous users as well.

Comment: This only work for `/general/search.json`, Why you need to redirect to login when the user requests the anon resource ?

Comment: Redirect to login should only happen when the session times out, otherwise it has to call the back-end. i.e In the normal scenario, when the user logs in and fires the search, the search back-end should be invoked. The scenario only when the user has logged in and performs search after the session times-out - only at this time, it should redirect to login page because the session has already expired...However , as an anonymous user, we shouldn't redirect under any scenarios, it should perform search. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Hi Guys, any advise would be greatly appreciated.